# How to use a custom background for selected button in MaterialButtonToggleGroup?

Tags: android, material-components-android, android-togglebutton

Here the expectation is as below-

[image]

Currently the design is-

[image]

activity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="420dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="420dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="448dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_two_toggle_bg"
        app:singleSelection="true"
        app:checkedButton="@+id/AppsBtn"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/AppsBtn"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Apps"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray"

            />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/FavouritesBtn"
            style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="208dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Favourites"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/light_gray"

            />
    </com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

**The Custom background can be a rectangular box as mentioned above.**
**How can we set the custom background for the selected button with padding?**